# Convert struct to slice of strings?

Tags: csv, go

I'm trying to write a CSV file using the package `encoding/csv`. All data I want to write per line is saved in a struct like this:

```
type record struct {
    Field0 string
    Field1 string
    Field2 string
    Field3 string
}
```

The csv package has a method called [Write](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#Writer.Write) that requires a slice of strings.

Is it possible to convert a struct to a slice of strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type record struct {
    Field0 string
    Field1 string
    Field2 string
    Field3 string
}

func main() {
    r := record{"f0", "f1", "f2", "f3"}
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", r)
    s := []string{
        r.Field0,
        r.Field1,
        r.Field2,
        r.Field3,
    }
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", s)
}
```

Output:

```
{"f0" "f1" "f2" "f3"}
["f0" "f1" "f2" "f3"]
```

Answer (score 3):

I find the https://github.com/fatih/structs package to be quite useful...

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/fatih/structs"
)

type record struct {
    Field0 string
    Field1 string
    Field2 string
    Field3 string
}

func main() {
    r := record{"f0", "f1", "f2", "f3"}
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", r)
    vals := structs.Values(r)
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", vals)
}
Output:

{"f0" "f1" "f2" "f3"}
["f0" "f1" "f2" "f3"]
```

Comment: Output is actually a slice of fields, not values.